# C# Image.FromStream(): Lost metadata when running in Windows 8 / 10

Tags: c#, image, web-services, png, platform

I have an application which retrieves an image from a web service. The web service would embed some metadata into the image before sending to the C# client.

This is part of the method. It retrieves the Stream from the Response object, and creates an Image from the stream. Note that I am using `System.Drawing.Image`, not the `System.Windows.Controls.Image` - this means that I cannot use any ImageSource or BitmapSource.

```
System.Drawing.Image img = null;
using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
    .......
}
return img;
```

The image looks perfectly fine, but there are metadata embedded inside. The image is in PNG format, and there is another method which would extract the information out from the `Image`. There are a total of six pieces of metadata embedded. The PNG format (the PNG chunks) is described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics). The data are saved under "tEXt" chunk.

```
public static Hashtable GetData(Image image)
{
    Hashtable metadata = null;
    data = new Hashtable();

    byte[] imageBytes;
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        image.Save(stream, image.RawFormat);
        imageBytes = new byte[stream.Length];
        imageBytes = stream.ToArray();
    }

    if (imageBytes.Length <= 8)
    {
        return null;
    }

    // Skipping 8 bytes of PNG header
    int pointer = 8;

    while (pointer < imageBytes.Length)
    {
        // read the next chunk
        uint chunkSize = GetChunkSize(imageBytes, pointer);
        pointer += 4;
        string chunkName = GetChunkName(imageBytes, pointer);
        pointer += 4;

        // chunk data -----
        if (chunkName.Equals("tEXt"))
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[chunkSize];
            Array.Copy(imageBytes, pointer, data, 0, chunkSize);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (byte t in data)
            {
                stringBuilder.Append((char)t);
            }

            string[] pair = stringBuilder.ToString().Split(new char[] { '\0' });
            metadata[pair[0]] = pair[1];
        }

        pointer += (int)chunkSize + 4;

        if (pointer > imageBytes.Length)
            break;
    }
    return data;
}

private static uint GetChunkSize(byte[] bytes, int pos)
{
    byte[] quad = new byte[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        quad[3 - i] = bytes[pos + i];
    }

    return BitConverter.ToUInt32(quad);
}

private static string GetChunkName(byte[] bytes, int pos)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        builder.Append((char)bytes[pos + i]);
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

In Windows 7, all the six pieces of metadata are detected and extracted out. So in short, in Windows 7 environment, I managed to get everything I need.

When I move this to a Windows 10 terminal (also tried Windows 8), things become different. I am only able to extract 2 pieces of metadata out from the `Image`.

Because my `GetData()` method converts the `Image` into `byte[]`, so I tried extracting the data right from the web service stream. I converted the stream into `byte[]`, and used the same technique to extract the metadata from the `byte[]`. I managed to get all 6 metadata back using this method.

So the question is: **What has changed?** It works totally fine in Windows 7, but not so in Windows 8 and 10. I can still get back the data, provided I don't turn the stream into an `Image`. Somewhere in the process, the metadata is lost. It is either lost when I convert the stream to `Image`, or when I convert the `Image` back to `byte[]`. As a side note, I have tried converting the `byte[]` into string. The string representation of the `byte[]` from the stream looks different from the `byte[]` from the `Image`. Using the correct encoder, I could see the 4 metadata missing in the later's `byte[]`.

Comment: Can you provide a sample image with metadata?

Comment: @GeorgeVovos Provide in what form..?

Comment: Are the bytes produced by image stream.ToArray() the same from one Windows version to another? (note you can remove the previous allocation, as ToArray does it). Otherwise, just make sure you pass opaque arrays of bytes, and don't use an intermediary image object. Also, your bytes -> string conversion for tEXt block is incorrect as text encoding is ISO-8859-1 per PNG spec. You should something like this `var text = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetString(bytes)` instead

Comment: @Jai Can you provide a png image with metadata

Comment: Can you provide source code for GetChunkSize ,GetChunkName.BTW,data variable is declared twice and VS raise a warning.

Comment: I will review the code, I find out the root problem, read my post updated, i will try to test your code in both environment.

Comment: I test your code in both win 7/10, and get the same issue. I modified the code to read stream from web or from file(saved during downloading stream), the issue is removed and get metadata in both win7/10. I can update my post and write the modified version.Do you need it?

Comment: Have a look to the new version as your require: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0Yq35b

Answer (score 4):

The metadata tEXt : is represented in ISO/IEC 8859-1

Try adding the following before you make your request:

```
 request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptCharset, "ISO-8859-1");
```

so, modify your code:

```
System.Drawing.Image img = null;

 //accept Charset "ISO-8859-1"
 request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptCharset, "ISO-8859-1");

using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
 Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
 img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
  .......
}
 return img;
```

just for information, can you post what is the windows EncodingName  in windows 7/ 8/10

use the powershell command to know:

```
[System.Text.Encoding]::Default.EncodingName
```

**Edit:**

I reviewed the source code of DOTNet System.Drawing.Image.FromStream
and found that statement:

```
  // [Obsolete("Use Image.FromStream(stream, useEmbeddedColorManagement)")]
    public static Image FromStream(Stream stream) { 
        return Image.FromStream(stream, false);
    }
```

try to use:

```
  Image.FromStream(stream, true); 
  or
 Image.FromStream(stream, true,true);
```

for details of the parameters:

```
  public static Image FromStream(
  Stream stream,
  bool useEmbeddedColorManagement,////true to use color management  information embedded in the data stream; otherwise, false. 
  bool validateImageData //true to validate the image data; otherwise, false.
  )
```

[Image.FromStream Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromstream(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Edit 2:**

I did an experiment on PNG image file with tEXT data:

I developed  a function to measure the size of the image in bytes  which is read by the function FromStream() and I executed on both win7 /win 10.

The following table, represent the real size of the image in bytes in both environment:

```
 The file size: 502,888 byte (real size on disk).     

 win 7         win10        function used
 569674        597298      Image.FromStream(stream, true,true)
 597343        597298      Image.FromStream(stream, true)
 597343        597298      Image.FromStream(stream, false)
```

You find that the size is different in both environment  and is different than
the real size in disk.

So, you expect that position of meta data  is changed (but not lost, only re-allocated)

I used  hexadecimal Editor tool to view the tTEXT chunk .

tEXT is at position 66 (in decimal) , from the beginning of file, and it is the same on both environment !!!

I  used my own metadata reader function and the result is the same and valid for both windows 7 or windows 10 ( NO LOSS OF DATA).

The official site for PNG format is: https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/

**Conclusion**

The function **Image.FromStream** is not suitable for reading metadata, the image file should be read in raw byte format not in image format, because the function FromStream reallocate the raw data  in such away to keep the image and its data without distortion (that is  the internals of the function in dotnet).

To read the metadata as described by PNG specs, you should read the stream in RAW BYTES from the beginning of the file as descriped by the specs.

I advice you to use the class library  MetadataExtractor to read meta data, and its result is very accurate in both windows 7 and  windows 10

You can install the library from nuget.
       install-Package MetadataExtractor

**Edit 3: The Proposed Solution**

Now the problem is resolved and the following class is valid for both win 7 , win 8

***The major change is reading the image file as Raw bytes***

```
class MetaReader 
{
    public static Hashtable GetData(string fname)
    {
        using (FileStream image = new FileStream(fname, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            Hashtable metadata = new Hashtable();
            byte[] imageBytes;

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                image.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                imageBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                Console.WriteLine(imageBytes.Length);
            }

            if (imageBytes.Length <= 8)
            {
                return null;
            }

            // Skipping 8 bytes of PNG header
            int pointer = 8;

            while (pointer < imageBytes.Length)
            {
                // read the next chunk
                uint chunkSize = GetChunkSize(imageBytes, pointer);
                pointer += 4;
                string chunkName = GetChunkName(imageBytes, pointer);
                pointer += 4;

                // chunk data -----
                if (chunkName.Equals("tEXt"))
                {
                    byte[] data = new byte[chunkSize];
                    Array.Copy(imageBytes, pointer, data, 0, chunkSize);
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    foreach (byte t in data)
                    {
                        stringBuilder.Append((char)t);
                    }

                    string[] pair = stringBuilder.ToString().Split(new char[] { '\0' });
                    metadata[pair[0]] = pair[1];
                    Console.WriteLine(metadata[pair[0]]);
                }

                pointer += (int)chunkSize + 4;

                if (pointer > imageBytes.Length)
                    break;
            }
            return metadata;
        }
    }

    private static uint GetChunkSize(byte[] bytes, int pos)
    {
        byte[] quad = new byte[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { quad[3 - i] = bytes[pos + i]; }

        return BitConverter.ToUInt32(quad, 0);

    }

    private static string GetChunkName(byte[] bytes, int pos)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { builder.Append((char)bytes[pos + i]); }

        return builder.ToString();

    }
}
```

**Reading Metadata from a Web Service:**

You can load image file from url as a stream, and read metadata on the fly.
Besides, you can create instance of System.Drawing.Image and do what ever processing on the image.
You can find a complete demo with source code at:

[Reading Metadata from  PNG loaded from  Web Stream -TryIt](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SR6wWV)

Comment: Sorry for being away after putting up a bounty. I just tried and it didn't work. Also, I could get the metadata out right from the web response stream. But once it is converted to `System.Drawing.Image` instance, the metadata is lost.

Comment: Anyway both Windows 7 and 10's default encoding is `Western European (Windows)`.

Comment: Nice findings there. What metadata reader function did you use? Is it simply MetadataExtractor library?

Comment: These are solid findings, but is there any alternatives that doesn't involve files? My application is directly getting a stream from web service, and needs to have an instance of `System.Drawing.Image`, and getting metadata at a later part.

Comment: Yes, you can download image as a stream and read metadata on the fly, without saving to disk. I did a working demo with source code at: https://dotnetfiddle.net/SR6wWV

Comment: I think you still didn't get the whole question totally right. I need to get the metadata out of the image instance at a much much later time, so I can only re-generate the stream back from the image. Anyway, your answer showed some good research, and I am glad to have understood more about images and PNG, so you got the bounty points :D

Comment: To process the image  much much later time, simply apply this rule: if you process the web stream directly(you still have the var stream), you can get metadata in both win7/10 , but if you convert webStream ->image->stream , behavioral is different in win7/10 . So process directly the web stream and get metadata, or save the web stream to file and latter load stream from the file in disk (BTW  this is the behavior of metaData Extrator no image object, only file stream)